# PrimeFaces SelectManyCheckbox - Uncheck all checkboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, checkbox, primefaces

Is there an easy way to select/deselect all checkboxes in a p:selectManyCheckbox using JavaScript?

I've got it working right now but my method seems overly complicated for something I feel should be simple from PrimeFaces

Code below:

The select boolean checkbox:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="multiSelectPerformanceCb"
    widgetVar="multiSelectPerformanceCb"
    value="#{cc.attributes.filter.selectedCriteria}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attributes.filter.performanceCriteria}"
            var="criteria" itemLabel="#{criteria.text}"
            itemValue="#{criteria.description}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

A method that is ran on a button click:

```
function performanceSliderBooleanClick()
    //Uncheck the inputs
    PF('multiSelectPerformanceCb').inputs.each(function(){
        this.checked = false;
    });

    //Remove ui-state-active from the outputs
    PF('multiSelectPerformanceCb').outputs.each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never used PrimeFaces, but having a look at their page I would try this (**IMPORTANT**: Replace `[yourformid]` with the `id` of the form (you don't show the form element in your question))...

***FOR UNSELECTING***:

```
function performanceSliderBooleanClick() {
    $('#[yourformid]\\:multiSelectPerformanceCb').find('div.ui-chkbox-box')
                                                 .removeClass('ui-state-active')
                                                 .find('span.ui-chkbox-icon')
                                                 .removeClass('ui-icon-check')
                                                 .addClass('ui-icon-blank');
}
```

***FOR TOGGLING (select all/unselect all)***:

```
function performanceSliderBooleanClick() {
    $('#[yourformid]\\:multiSelectPerformanceCb').find('div.ui-chkbox-box')
                                                 .toggleClass('ui-state-active')
                                                 .find('span.ui-chkbox-icon')
                                                 .toggleClass('ui-icon-check ui-icon-blank');
}
```

Comment: this works for a JavaScript solution for handling the UI but won't work as far as hooking up with the backend. I was looking more for a PrimeFaces solution potentially using a widgetVar or built in PrimeFaces method but I gave you an upvote because I like this solution as far as simplifying the UI cleanup i was doing in multiple lines

Comment: @TonyScialo: your solution is more in line with the widget approach of PrimeFaces and does not rely on the structural design of the components. You could make some small changes to the[ source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.selectmanycheckbox.js) of this component and make it a real widget function (check other comparable components). You can then file this as an enhancement in the issuelist with a pull request.